# How should I parallelize a mix of cpu- and network-intensive tasks (in Celery)

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, celery

I have a job that scans a network file system (can be remote), pulls many files, runs a computation on them and pushes the results (per file) into a DB. I am in process of moving this to Celery so that it can be scaled up. The number of files can get really huge (1M+).

I am not sure what design approach to take, specifically:

### Uniform "end2end" tasks

A task gets a *batch* (list of N files), pulls them, computes and uploads results.

(Using batches rather than individual files is for optimizing the connection to the remote file system and the DB, although it is a pure heuristics at this point)

Clearly, a task would spend a large part of it waiting for I/O, so we'll need to play with number of worker processes (much more than # of CPUs), so that I have enough tasks running (computing) concurrently.

**pro:** simple design, easier coding and control.
**con:** probably will need to tune the process pool size individually per installation, as it would depend on environment (network, machines etc.)

### Split into dedicated smaller tasks

download, compute, upload (again, batches).
This option is appealing intuitively, but I don't actually see the advantage.

I'd be glad to get some references to tutorials on concurrency design, as well as design suggestions.

Comment: Is there an upper bound to the duration within which you want the entire process to be completed?

Comment: @DivijSehgal yes. It could be negotiable, but it should be within reason. Let's say, a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of celery, you can write a simple python script which runs on `k*cpu_count` threads just to connect to remote servers and fetch files without celery.

Personally, I found that k value in between 4 to 7 gives better results in terms of CPU utilization for IO bound tasks. Depending on the number of files produced or the rate at which you want to consume, you can use a suitable number of threads.

Alternatively, you can use celery + gevent or celery with threads if your tasks are IO bound.

For computation and updating DB you can use celery so that you can scale as per your requirements dynamically. If you are too many tasks at a time which need DB connection, you should use DB connection pooling for workers.

Comment: thanks. Pulling the entire mass of files to be processed up front is not feasible, so the both processes should run in parallel, which complicates the system in the early stage it is now.
Could you elaborate why using celery for I/O tasks is not a good idea?

Comment: You don't need to pull all files in the beginning. The script can pull incrementally. Celery uses fork for new workers process which will be overhead. You can use celery + gevent to if your tasks with for IO tasks.

Answer (score 2):

How long does it take to scan the network file system compared to computation per file?

How does the hierarchy of the remote file system look like? Are the files evenly distributed? How can you use this in your advantage ?

I would follow a process like this:
1. In one process, list the first two levels of the root remote target folder.
2. For each of the discovered folders, spin up a separate celery process that further lists the content of those folders. You may also want to save the location of the discovered files just in case things go wrong.
3. After you have listed the content of the remote file system and all celery processes that list files terminate you can go in processing mode.
4. You may want to list files with 2 processes and use the rest of your cores to start doing per file work.

NB: Before doing everything in python I would also investigate how does bash tools like xargs and find work together in remote file discovery. Xargs allows you to spin up multiple C processes that do what you want. That might be the most efficient way to do the remote file discovery and then pipe everything to you python code.

Comment: I can't say as many different file systems may be added in the future, e.g. Google Drive, DropBox etc. You miss one step in the process, which is *pulling* the files for processing, which is IMHO the most I/O costly. As for your suggestion in NB, it is interesting but I don't have the mandate to re-architecture the system at this point. We already have the system in Python but it is limited to one machine

Comment: Yes indeed. If retrieving the file from NAS is comparable in time with the actual file processing then you may want to have a different stage for that as well. You could also do some file fingerprinting/timestamping (which may be accomplished in the directory traversal) so you don't do work if not needed.